# xstring substitution with font commands fails in error

Tags: errors, xstring, substitution

I want to substitute some spaces with normal font `\dots` in between name parts typeset in `\ttfamily`.

Below example works except for the commented part which fails miserably with the error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] \StrSubstitute{\pxname}{ }{\normaldots}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

%normaldots
\newcommand{\normaldots}{{\fontfamily{\familydefault}\fontseries{\seriesdefault}\fontshape{\shapedefault}\selectfont\normalsize\dots}}

\newcommand{\pxlastname}{Van der Laak}
\newcommand{\pxfirstname}{Cor}
\newcommand{\pxname}{\pxlastname\normaldots\pxfirstname}

\begin{document}
{\ttfamily\scshape\Huge\MakeLowercase{\pxname\normaldots test}}
\newline
%\StrSubstitute{\pxname}{ }{\normaldots}[\pxoutput]
%{\ttfamily\scshape\Huge\MakeLowercase{\pxoutput\normaldots test}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xstring`, by default, does complete expansion on its arguments. The biggest problem is, therefore, the fact that also `\normaldots` gets expanded, which you don't want.

You can "robustify" the `\normaldots` command with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring,etoolbox}

%normaldots
\newrobustcmd{\normaldots}{{\normalfont\normalsize\dots}}

\newcommand{\pxlastname}{Van der Laak}
\newcommand{\pxfirstname}{Cor}
\newcommand{\pxname}{\pxlastname\normaldots\pxfirstname}

\begin{document}
{\ttfamily\scshape\Huge\MakeLowercase{\pxname\normaldots test}}
\newline

\StrSubstitute{\pxname}{ }{\normaldots}[\pxoutput]
{\ttfamily\scshape\Huge\MakeLowercase{\pxoutput\normaldots test}}

\end{document}
```

In this way, `\normaldots` passes unexpanded through the `\edef` performed by `xstring` when doing `\StrSubstitute`.

Note also that `\normaldots` can be defined in a simpler way than yours.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution with stringstrings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\protectededef\protected@edef
\makeatother

%\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand{\normaldots}{{\fontfamily{\familydefault}\fontseries{\seriesdefault}\fontshape{\shapedefault}\selectfont\normalsize\dots}}

\newcommand{\pxlastname}{Van der Laak}
\newcommand{\pxfirstname}{Cor}
\newcommand{\pxname}{\pxlastname\normaldots\pxfirstname}

\newcommand\pxoutput{\dpxlastname\normaldots\pxfirstname}

\begin{document}
{\ttfamily\scshape\Huge\MakeLowercase{\pxname\normaldots test}}
\newline
%\StrSubstitute{\pxname}{ }{\normaldots}[\pxoutput]

\encodetoken[1]{\normaldots}
\convertword[e]{\pxlastname}{~}{\normaldots}
\retokenize{\thestring}

\protectededef\dpxlastname{\thestring}
\decodetoken[1]{\normaldots}

{\ttfamily\scshape\Huge\MakeLowercase{\pxoutput\normaldots test}}
\end{document}
```